# Trouble insalling emscripten — source: no such file or directory: ../../../../../../Downloads/emsdk-portable/emsdk_env.sh

Tags: terminal, cmake, emscripten

MacOS 10.12 Sierra

Trying to install emscripten via [these instructions](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html) (with the goal of installing [opencv.js](https://github.com/ucisysarch/opencvjs)). I checked all the dependencies [as listed here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/toolchain_what_is_needed.html#toolchain-test-which-dependencies-are-installed) and they all returned valid except `cmake` which returns no response. I installed the CMake application and it's sitting in my Applications folder. I assumed this is OK and moved on. Also, the commands as listed do not work with the `./` in front, I just get `no such file or directory` errors. If I do `emsdk update` the commands work fine. So everything works fine until `source ./emsdk_env.sh`. My terminal's telling me to do `source ../../../../../../Downloads/emsdk-portable/emsdk_env.sh`. Attempting this anyway results in:

```
source: no such file or directory: ../../../../../../Downloads/emsdk-portable/emsdk_env.sh
```

Why is it different? Do I have to be in a specific directory when installing all this? Thanks for any help.

Edit1:

Did `emsdk list` and have the following stats if at all necessary:

```
*     clang-e1.37.22-64bit      INSTALLED
*     node-4.1.1-64bit          INSTALLED
*     emscripten-1.37.22        INSTALLED
*    sdk-1.37.22-64bit          INSTALLED
```